# Why does Voldemort allow Fenrir to be a Death Eater?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

Why does Voldemort allow Fenrir to be a Death Eater, when he was a werewolf which is considered half breed?

Considering Voldemort's main goal was to kill all half breeds and half bloods, why does he let Fenrir attend meetings?

Comment: Voldemort isn't particularly against magical creatures or part-animals. He brings giants and dementors into the dark army without a second thought. He's against muggles, and particularly muggles having any power over wizards (e.g. the wizards having to be in hiding). In order to advocate wizard supremacy, he's harsh on muggleborn wizards and muggle sympathisers (e.g. anyone who doesn't want a reign of evil terror the muggles). but, yeah, he's all good with evil creatures.

Answer (score 61):

## He wasn't a death eater.

> "Will you summon 'im? 'ere?" said Scabior, sounding awed, terrified.
>
> "No," snarled Greyback, "I haven't got - they say he's using the
> Malfoy's place as a base. We'll take the boy there."
>
> Harry thought he knew why Greyback was not calling Voldemort. The
> werewolf might be allowed to wear Death Eater robes when they wanted
> to use him, but only Voldemort's inner circle were branded with the
> Dark Mark: Greyback had not been granted this highest honor.

So Greyback wasn't in the inner circle because he was a werewolf. And Voldemort's goal isn't necessarily to kill all half breeds- He doesn't really have anything against Hagrid for example- His goal is more against Muggle-borns. So Voldemort doesn't have a problem with an extra servant working for him.

Comment: wasn't voldemort's goal more to become an immortal lich king instead of a genozide? after all, he drives mainly to kill harry for the time beeing. imho the character is unreasonable and badly written, a true lich could simply wait for the boy to die from old age, lol

Comment: @clockw0rk- His main goal is to basically rule the world in his own ways- Going against muggles and muggle borns. In order to rule the world he must beat the Order of the phoenix, Dumbledore's army, etc. One of the main people who lead and give hope to the resistance is Harry Potter. That's why he must be eliminated. Another one of Voldemort's main Goals is to become immortal- And thanks to the prophecy, Voldemort can't live while Harry is also alive. That is the main reason why he wants to kill Harry.

Answer (score 23):

[The other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/244868/100430) points out that Greyback was not, in fact, a full-fledged Death Eater. As for why Voldemort utilizes him at all, it is apparently because he provides a useful service. From Chapter Sixteen of *Half-Blood Prince*:

> “You haven’t heard of him?” Lupin’s hands closed convulsively in his lap. “Fenrir Greyback is, perhaps, the most savage werewolf alive today. He regards it as his mission in life to bite and to contaminate as many people as possible; he wants to create enough werewolves to overcome the wizards. Voldemort has promised him prey in return for his services. Greyback specializes in children.... Bite them young, he says, and raise them away from their parents, raise them to hate normal wizards. Voldemort has threatened to unleash him upon people’s sons and daughters; it is a threat that usually produces good results.”

Answer (score 3):

### Fenrir isn’t a Death Eater, just allowed the robes.

Fenrir Greyback is not a Death Eater - he is permitted to wear their robes, but he is not a true member of the Death Eaters.

> “He knew who this was: Fenrir Greyback, the werewolf who was permitted to wear Death Eater robes in return for his hired savagery.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)*</sup></sub>

Every Death Eater gets a Dark Mark - some considered allies of Voldemort, like Narcissa, do not have one, but everyone who is actually a member of the Death Eaters has one.

> “The Dark Mark. It is not as clear as it was, an hour or so ago, when it burnt black, but you can still see it. Every Death Eater had the sign burnt into him by the Dark Lord. It was a means of distinguishing each other, and his means of summoning us to him. When he touched the Mark of any Death Eater, we were to Disapparate, and Apparate, instantly, at his side.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 36 (The Parting of the Ways)*</sup></sub>

Greyback is never mentioned as having one, and declined to summon Voldemort when he held Harry captive, first saying “I haven’t got” before deciding to go to Malfoy Manor, implying that he most likely doesn’t have one.

> “To hell with the Ministry,’ growled Greyback. ‘They’ll take the credit, and we won’t get a look in. I say we take him straight to You-Know-Who.’
> ‘Will you summon ’im? ’Ere?’ said Scabior, sounding awed, terrified.
>
> ‘No,’ snarled Greyback, ‘I haven’t got – they say he’s using the Malfoys’ place as a base. We’ll take the boy there.’
>
> Harry thought he knew why Greyback was not calling Voldemort. The werewolf might be allowed to wear Death Eater robes when they wanted to use him, but only Voldemort’s inner circle were branded with the Dark Mark: Greyback had not been granted this highest honour.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)*</sup></sub>

Greyback is also not present, and his absence is not noted, at Death Eater gatherings, such as when Voldemort summoned all the Death Eaters to the graveyard, and the one held in Malfoy Manor. Furthermore, at the gathering in
Malfoy Manor, Voldemort makes it clear that he does not consider werewolves equal, which indicates he would not want to give one a position of high honor.

> “The dwindling of the pure-bloods is, says Professor Burbage, a most desirable circumstance … she would have us all mate with Muggles … or, no doubt, werewolves …’
> Nobody laughed this time: there was no mistaking the anger and contempt in Voldemort’s voice.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, the Death Eaters as an organization does not have a high opinion of werewolves, as they laughed when Voldemort revealed that the niece of Bellatrix and the Malfoys married one.

> “She has just married the werewolf, Remus Lupin. You must be so proud.’
>
> There was an eruption of jeering laughter from around the table. Many leaned forward to exchange gleeful looks; a few thumped the table with their fists. The great snake, disliking the disturbance, opened its mouth wide and hissed angrily, but the Death Eaters did not hear it, so jubilant were they at Bellatrix and the Malfoys’ humiliation.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, it would be logical to conclude that while Greyback is allowed to wear the Death Eater robes, he is not actually a Death Eater.

### But, Voldemort’s army includes Dark creatures.

While Greyback is not a Death Eater, and Voldemort is unlikely to allow a werewolf the honor of becoming one, Voldemort’s army is not solely, or even mainly, comprised of Death Eaters. The Death Eaters are his most trusted, innermost circle of followers, but not the bulk of his army. His army also includes a number of Dark creatures, which he actively seeks to recruit.

> “Well, firstly, he wants to build up his army again,’ said Sirius. ‘**In the old days he had huge numbers at his command: witches and wizards he’d bullied or bewitched into following him, his faithful Death Eaters, a great variety of Dark creatures.** You heard him planning to recruit the giants; well, they’ll be just one of the groups he’s after. He’s certainly not going to try and take on the Ministry of Magic with only a dozen Death Eaters.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5 (The Order of the Phoenix)*</sup></sub>

Voldemort himself tells his Death Eaters that he will have an army of creatures whom all fear. He plans to bring the giants back from banishment and have the Dementors join forces with him.

> “The Dementors will join us … they are our natural allies … we will recall the banished giants … I shall have all my devoted servants returned to me, and an army of creatures whom all fear …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

The recruitment of werewolves as a species is also included in his plan - Greyback is not an exceptional case in that regard. Most werewolves ally themselves with Voldemort.

> “I’ve been living among my fellows, my equals,’ said Lupin. ‘Werewolves,’ he added, at Harry’s look of incomprehension. ‘Nearly all of them are on Voldemort’s side.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 16 (A Very Frosty Christmas)*</sup></sub>

In fact, one of Greyback’s uses to Voldemort is his ability to rally the other werewolves to Voldemort’s cause.

> “But Greyback is not like that. At the full moon he positions himself close to victims, ensuring that he is near enough to strike. He plans it all. And this is the man Voldemort is using to marshal the werewolves. I cannot pretend that my particular brand of reasoned argument is making much headway against Greyback’s insistence that we werewolves deserve blood, that we ought to revenge ourselves on normal people.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 16 (A Very Frosty Christmas)*</sup></sub>

While Voldemort considers werewolves beneath wizards, and would not want one among his most trusted inner circle, he is perfectly willing to include them as a a component in his army.